# show video on qlabel using opengl

Tags: opengl, qt5, gstreamer

I have a project that contain 3 labels. I should set text to two of them every 3 sec. and for the third label, I have to show a video frames on that.
my video frames came from a Gstreamer pipeline and I show frames when they ready. when a frame provided, I get the frame and convert it to image and then show images on a label.(my Gstreamer pipeline decode video with APU)
every things works fine. but it consume CPU alot.
my question is: how can I reduce CPU usage? is it make any difference to implement my code with QOpenglWindow? and if yes, do you have an example?
my system is an Embedded Linux imx6 and qt verson is 5.5.

thanks in advance.

Comment: That's impossible to answer without seeing some code.

Comment: It is hard to answer your question because it contains too few details. If you care to share your relevant code it will be easier. For example you say "Gstreamer pipeline" but are you using Qstreamer as wrapped in QMultiMedia or by using your own code? What does the code look like that fetches frames into the label?